# How can prevent dotnet core SignalR json serilizer from generate invalid json format

Tags: json, .net, serialization, signalr, .net-5

I create web-app  with .net 5 and use SignalR for real-time communicate.
but when I send message to client with `SendAsync()` like this:

```cs
await _hubContext
                .Clients
                .Group(groupName)
                .SendAsync(method, data, cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Boolean value present in invalid JSON format `false` => `False`
and `true` => `True`.

Also string value present in single quote `'` instead of double quote `"`
and `null` value present as `None`
So client side in python can parse result and convert to JSON object!
How can I prevent dotnet core SignalR JSON serilizer from generate invalid format result.

Thank.